# Calculated width wrong in Chrome, fine in FFox / IE?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Very weird bug im experiencing.

When getting the width of a cell, in Chrome, using jQuery (or plain old javascript), it appears to blindly looks at the css `width` property, whereas firefox actually reports the *rendered* width.

Example shown here http://jsfiddle.net/Dg7cg/

Using Chrome: '30.0.1599.69 m', rendered output here: [image]

I'm expecting a value of around 107px, but Chrome seems to report 23px.

Does anyone know of a javascript function that will report the 'true' width from within chrome?

Comment: Worth looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212608/why-is-my-table-cell-width-wrong-in-chrome - may even be a duplicate, but I am not so sure about the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an unintentional regression in Chrome which is tracked by https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290399

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem)['width'];
```

On some browsers

```
document.getComputedStyle(elem)['width'];
```

will work.